# virtualenv gets wrong python?

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

files from the Grinberg flask tutorial on git won't work for me locally unless I add `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the first line - but I thought the default python for my xubuntu apt-get installation of virtualenv was supposed to be python 2.7 ?

Can I invoke virtualenv in a way that ensures the right python gets used so I don't have to add the shebang to every file I checkout from git?

I also have to `chmod 755` these files before they work in my local virtualenv.

Am I causing these problems somehow? Is there a way to avoid having to change the files every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `env`, that essentially means the first `python` instance in your `PATH` will be used.

What is the output when you do `which python`? Which version is `virtualenv` using instead?

It may be that you're using the system `python` instead of the `virtualenv` without that change.

How are you actually invoking the scripts?

If you invoke them directly from `bin/python` in the `virtualenv` environment you want to use, then it should use that `python`.

Otherwise, if you just want to use `python` without a path, it's best to `source` the `activate` script in the `virtualenv` you want to use.

Comment: My problem was invoking the scripts like ./file.py  I had been doing source /venv/bin/activate so just invoking the scripts properly as suggested above works fine and solves the permissions problem too. If anyone else gets my error just do as above and invoke script as python file.py   then all is well!   Thank you for prompt help! :-)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Since it sounds like this answer solved your problem, please accept it as the answer. =)

Comment: sorry this is Day1 for me here ... if there is a method for me to credit your answer I don't see it.  In any event... thanks!   :-)

Comment: Yes. Underneath the arrows and score for my answer, there should be a check mark that you can click to accept the answer. Some more info about stuff like that can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour